# JSON Parsing - How to get rid of leading tab character in front of data?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to remove a tab character from a json_encoded data from php?  Every time I try to fetch data from the script as JSON enocded format I use the following code below to parse my data but can not get the **jsonStr** to be parsed.

The error I am getting is

> Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON
>   data

**Code**

```
        jsonStr = data.toString();
        jsonStr = JSON.stringify(jsonStr.replace("\t",""));
        totJSON = JSON.parse(jsonStr['totalActionItems']);
```

How do I resolve this error to parse a well formed json string correctly?

EDIT

**Corrected Parsing Code (JS)**

```
 $.ajax({url: "/dashboard/chartdata.php?chart=buildup", success: function(data)
     {
            jsonStr = data.replace(/\t/g, "");
            console.log(jsonStr);
            json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
            totJSON = json['totalActionItems'];
```

**PHP Code**

```
function getData($field, $rows)
    {
        $minDate = $rows[0][$field];
        $maxDate = $rows[count($rows)-1][$field];
        $date = $minDate;
        $findDate = $minDate;
        $idx = 0;
        $tot = 0;
        $dates = array();
        $numActionItems = array();
        while ($date < $maxDate)
        {
            if ($rows[$idx][$field] == $date)
            {
                $tot += $rows[$idx]['numactionitems'];
                $idx++;
            }   
            $timestamp = strtotime($date);
            $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . "+1 days"));
            $numActionItems[] = array('x'=>$timestamp*1000, 'y'=>$tot);
        }
        return $numActionItems;
    }


function getBuildUpData($field)
    {
        $manageCharts = new manageCharts();
        $rows = $manageCharts->buildup($field);
        $items = getData($field, $rows);
        return $items;
    }

if (isset($_GET['chart']) && $_GET['chart'] == 'buildup')
    {
        $json = json_encode(['totalActionItems' => getBuildUpData('assigneddate'),
                                                'ecdItems' => getBuildUpData('ecd'),
                                                'originalDueItems' => getbuildUpData('duedate'),
                                                'closedItems' => getBuildUpData('closeddate')]);
        echo $json;     
    }
```

Comment: This is not PHP, this is jQuery parsing JSON. How about posting your PHP code that echoes JSON? are you printing anything before json data?

Comment: That is what I suspected but I have searched for and have been unable to find a echo statement that corresponds to the leading tab.  I tried to remove the tab from the json string but that did not work successfully, and I also tried to find the anywhere where there is a leading tab in my included files.

Comment: have you tried to run the code directly to see json data? try that in CLI. Also after that comment out `echo $json;` and echo something else just to check.

Comment: Yes, I am able to run the code with a leading 1 which is also tabbed over.  I am not sure where (or how) to detect my leading tab.

Comment: you output the data in console in your front-end using `conseole`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have been using firebug.  I believe I have resolved the problem and get back json parsed data for processing.  I will post my code in the edit.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code helped produce the correct json for processing.

```
jsonStr = data.replace(/\t/g, "");
//console.log(jsonStr);
json = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
totJSON = json['totalActionItems'];
```